# Java, changing boolean column to checkbox in jTable when using rs2xml for populating jTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I am using a jTable which is populated with mysql db data using rs2xml

```
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

I have some columns that are displayed by boolean values, but these must become checkboxes. I understand that i have to write my own AbstractTableModel, but I don't know how...

Can one of you give an example of how you extend the AbstractTableModel and use it in your code?

Comment: Unless the underlying data type represents a Boolean (and assuming that rs2XML honors the database columns) there's little you can do. The better choice would be to use your own TableModel, which you can control, and parse the results from the ResultSet

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I have tried a mysql bit(1) datatype and a tinyint(1) datatype, mysql has no real boolean(true, false) datatype sadly enough...

Comment: Then I would assume that rs2xml either isn't honoring the column type or is simply ignoring it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some columns that are displayed by boolean values, but these must become checkboxes.

Then you can override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the JTable:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
        {
            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

            if (o != null)
            {
                return o.getClass();
            }
        }

        return Object.class;
    }
};
```

Or as suggested you can create your own TableModel. This is not difficult, again all you really need to do is implement the `getColumnClass(...)` method, but you need to write your own code to load the data into the TableModel.

See the `TableFromDatabase.java` example code found [Table From Database](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for example code to replace your DbUtils class.

Comment: Yes thanks camickr, it works!!!, i made my own class for JTable, MyTable with your code and used it. I don't understand the code but it works... thanks a lot.